# I have a short html form with a php for loop which allows the user to build the same form up to ten times on the page

Tags: php, for-loop

The $i variable is each field and is populated in the 'inp' boxes which are just input boxes and sboxes which are just select boxes. There is only one form when the page loads and it has all the criteria for a trainer to be added. The trainer name would be trainer_name1 on the first form. If they chose to hit the new button they could fill out the information for another trainer, the input box for the second form for 'name' would just be trainer_name2 and all the other fields are named respectively to what they are in the form. As new forms are built in just adds the next consecutive number onto the end of whatever the field might be named.

Here is my code:

```
<fieldset><legend>Trainer Request</legend></fieldset>
<tr><td><input type='button' onClick="if (show_item(1,10, 0)) { this.style.display = 'none'; }" value='New'></td></tr>
<?php
$contact_array = array('ACCEPTED TRAINING','DECLINED TRAINING','LEFT MESSAGE FOR TRAINING ACCEPTANCE',
        'NEED TO CONTACT TO SEE IF INTERESTED',
        'NEED PAPERWORK/TRAINING',
        'NEED SIGNED CONTRACT AND PAPERWORK',
        'NEED TO COMPLETE TRAINING');

for ($i = 10; $i > 0; $i=$i-1)
    {
    echo "<table id='hidden$i' style='display:none;'><tr>";
    echo "<td>Date</td><td>Status</td></tr>";  
    echo "<tr><td>"; inp("date$i"); echo "</td><td>";
    sbox("contact$i", $contact_array, 0, 'wide2');
    echo "</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Facility</td><td>"; 
    inp("facility$i",50);   echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Trainer Name</td><td>";
    inp("trainer_name$i",35);
    echo "<tr><td>Distance From</td><td>";
    sbox("distance_from$i", array('1','2','5','10','15','20','25','30','40','50','60','70','80','90','100'));
    echo "</td></tr>

    <tr><td>Phone</td><td>";
    inp("phone$i",13,'phone');
    echo "</td><tr><tr><td>Email</td><td>";
    inp("email$i",50);
    echo "</tr><tr><td>Address 1</td><td>";
    inp("addr1$i",50);
    echo "</tr><tr><td>Address 2</td><td>";
    inp("addr2$i",10);
    echo " City ";
    inp("city$i",20);
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>State</td><td>";
    inp("state$i",2);
        echo " Zip ";
    inp("zip$i",'zip');
    echo "</td></tr><tr><td>Notes</td><td>";
    tbox("notes$i", 40, 3);
    echo "</td></tr></table>";
    }
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
show_item(1,10,1);
</script>
```

As you can see down here I'm building a link which would name the link whatever the trainer name is, in this case trainer_name1 is Tim Jackson, so i've just built a hyperlink with his name.

```
<?php
// print_r ($_GET);

    echo sendback_link($_GET['trainer_name1'], 'ACS/TrainerLookup', 'trainer_id=trainer_code&trainer_name=trainer_name'); 


?>
```

I'm confused on how to add a dynamic link like this into the for loop so as the form builds 1 - 10 each trainer_name2, trainer_name3, trainer_name4 etc etc. will have their names hyperlinked.

I'm thinking I create a new variable for the number 1-10 and append it onto the $_GET[trainer_name$].. something like that?

I hope that makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are aware that PHP runs on the server, and that the user is using a browser, right? PHP generates the page that they'll see, then dies. When the data hits the client's browser, there is no PHP, just plain html/css/js. So if you want the user to add forms, write that functionality in on-page, or source linked, JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to add more content or replace content on a webpage that has already been generated with PHP.

I think what you are trying to do can be achieved using AJAX.
AJAX is a technique for creating dynamic webpages. AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page.

In your case, the process can be described in 3 steps:

- the browser making a new request to your server (using javascript)
- the server processes the request and sends some information back to the browser
- the browser deals with that information (again using javascript) and then updates part of the webpage

There is an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) that shows how you can dynamically change the webpage contents.

Although, if you are allowed to, I would suggest that you use a javascript framework like jQuery which simplifies the whole process (google it for download and instructions on how to use).

You can read about using AJAX with jQuery [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) and reading the examples that follow to better understand how you can use it.

If you are going to try and use AJAX with jQuery or simply AJAX I suggest that you try it on a test page to get a simple working example, then adding a few things and checking to see if everything works as expected. When the test page is working as expected, import the code to your page.

This is how I would do it, there may be better or easier ways to do it.